# How to provision a site collection using Sharepoint framework and sp-pnp-js or pnpjs?

Tags: typescript, sharepoint-online, spfx

I just created my first SharePoint Framework web part after a lot of sweating. I was able to deploy the pnp partner pack to Azure and from there I created a SharePoint site from a template.

Now my question is, how can I reproduce the same Site provisioning functionality that the pnp partner pack is using in azure, but this time from within a Web Part which is created via SPFx? So, can someone guide me how to utilize the provisioning engine in pnpjs or sp-pnp-js and some code examples please?

Thank you.

PS: there are a lot of documentations around and I can't rap my head around as where to start reading and which one is the latest version or what is outdated.